# Sorting the letters of a one worded string in Python?

Tags: python, string, sorting

```
x = 'yellow'
print(sorted(x))
```

returns

```
['e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'y']
```

What I want it to return

ellowy

How ran I make it return `'ellowy'` without the letters being in a list?

Comment: Thank you everyone for very quick replies.  Very helpful.

Comment: Although stackoverflow is a great resource please note that you would have easily gotten your answer by googleing "list to string python" I'm 100% positive the first result will be the correct solution. I'm not blaming you though, it is sometimes hard to find the right terms to google, no harm done and glad you learnd this!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually `sorted()` when used on a string always returns a list of individual characters.
so you should use `str.join()` to make a string out of that list.

```
>>> x = 'yellow'
>>> ''.join(sorted(x))
'ellowy'
```

Answer (score 11):

The `join()` method of a string joins each element of its argument with copies of the given string object as a delimiter between each item. Many people find this a weird and counterintuitive way to do things, but by joining the elements with an empty string you can convert a list of strings into a single string:

```
x = 'yellow' 
print(''.join(sorted(x)))
```

Answer (score 9):

```
x = 'yellow' 
print(''.join(sorted(x)))
```

Comment: Three identical (correct) answers at the same time.. the only solution is to upvote them all.

Answer (score 4):

If you want for Guido to [hate](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) you, try :

```
reduce(lambda l,r: l+r, sorted(x))
```

;-)

in python 3 you would need to import it from the functools package

Comment: I didn't downvote but maybe it was for an overcomplicated solution to a simple problem? :)

Comment: some people just don't recognize a joke - thx for the zero ;-)